# MVC html.dropdownlist forgeting selected value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So i created a dropdown list i change the language depending on the selected value in the list, but when it submits i loose the selected value and it resets. is there any way to remember what i selected when i submit it?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home", new { @onsubmit = @"$(#Languages option:selected).text();" }))
@Html.DropDownList("Languages", Test.Configuration.GetLanguages().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value }), new{@onchange = @"$(form).submit();"})
```

Comment: Does you model contain a property named `Languages`?

Comment: instead of `Html.DropDownList` use strongly typed `Html.DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the syntax

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, new SelectList(Test.Configuration.GetLanguages().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value })))
```

Then MVC knows to use that field to store the selected option from the dropdown list.

Per the comment below, this is how I would declare language in the model:

PageViewModel.cs

```
public class PageViewModel {
    ...
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public SelectList Languages { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult Index(PageViewModel pageViewModel)
    {
        //put breakpoint on the return view and after you submit a selection you'll see that the pageViewModel argument has the language of what you selected
        return View(new PageViewModel
            {
                Language = "English",
                Languages = new SelectList(new List<string>
                {
                    "English",
                    "Danish",
                    "Spanish",
                    "French"
                })
            });
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model MvcPlayground.Controllers.PageViewModel
<h2>Languages!</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, Model.Languages)
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

MVC will use the language property to determine the selected item on postback, as long as you're passing it around properly.

Comment: Im getting my Languages from the Config file, i have a list of Languages in my Model but it is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetLanguages()` is this a problem? i suppose i can work with this?

Comment: If you're talking about model.Language, model.Language should just be the 'selected value' of your list of selectlistitems (I assume the languages are stored as strings, so it would be a string as well). MVC will .ToString() the value of those items to determine which option is selected.

Comment: I might need to see your controller action as well to understand more about your page. The viewmodel should have the selected value in it when you submit your page.

Comment: I can't say  `m=>m.Language` just `Model.Language` do you maybe know why is that?

Comment: I also added my example view code to complete the MCE

Comment: I can't access m=>m.Language... i don't get it.. here is the controler i call: 
` public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string Languages)
     { if (controlCookie.Value != Languages)
         {    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
             if (cookie != null)
                 cookie.Value = Languages;
             else
             {
                 cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
                 cookie.Value = culture;
                 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
}
             Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

             return Redirect(path)`

Comment: I would need to see your View page. You can edit it into the OP and comment here to notify me..

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code like this

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //pass the Enumerable<SelectListItem>  in to viewbag
       ViewBag.Countrys = new List<SelectListItem>{
                new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "-Select-", Value = "-1"},
                 new SelectListItem {  Text = "India", Value = "100"},
                  new SelectListItem {  Text = "US", Value = "101"},

            };


        return View();
    }
```

you need a model like this

```
 public class HomeModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in view

```
     @model Stratergy.Models.Home.HomeModel

@using (@Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "your controller"))
{
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Personal Form:</legend>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FirstName)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CountryId,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Countrys)

    <input type="submit" value="Finish" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

And you can get the selected value in the model when formpost

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourAction(HomeModel homeModel)
    {

        return Json(new { Result = "OK"});
    }
```

Comment: for the love of God, this is my model `@model Models.IndexPageModel`
Why can't i say model => model.Language, just Model.Language? i don't get it?